# leaflet non-geographical map with tilelayer: the map appears to have a vertical offset?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In order to maintain a community project I picked up for a gaming community, I'm trying to understand how leaflet is working. In particular, I'm trying to display a non-geographical map using a custom tile service.

Based on the leaflet documentation and on a series of tutorials and stackoverflow answers, the best I've been able to come up with is the following code. The markers are added to [0,0] and [maxLat, maxLong] to verify if they are aligned with the map (the issue I'm trying to solve on my project is that they are not):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
        #map { height: 1080px; width: 1920px; }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        var yx = L.latLng;

        var xy = function(x, y) {
        if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {
            return yx(x[1], x[0]);
        }
        return yx(y, x);
        };


        var minZoom = 0;
        var maxZoom = 7;
        var img = [
            18475,
            12791
        ];

        L.CRS.MySimple = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
            transformation: new L.Transformation(1 / 128, 0, 1 / 128, 0)
        });

        var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(img)];

        var map = L.map("map", {
            attributionControl: false,
            crs: L.CRS.MySimple,
            maxBounds: bounds,
            minZoom: minZoom,
            maxZoom: maxZoom
        });

        L.tileLayer('https://d1w6xpzk1h0aj5.cloudfront.net/kuban/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            bounds: bounds,
            noWrap: true,
            minZoom: minZoom,
            maxZoom: maxZoom,
            tms: true,
            continuousWorld: false,
            maxNativeZoom: 7
        }).addTo(map);

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        L.marker(L.latLng([ 0, 0 ])).addTo(map);
        L.marker(L.latLng(xy(img))).addTo(map);
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

If I open this on my browser, the map is displayed correctly at all zoom levels (i.e. the tiles are provided in the right order and leaflet is stitching them as expected). The problem is that the map is vertically off-center and the markers, though they're perfectly aligned horizontally, have a vertical offset.

This is precisely the problem I also have on my main project.

What am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: Hhhmm, the tiles seem to be aligned to the bottom-left of the game world, but your [0,0] is at the top-left. Are you sure you've got the right coordinate system for this game world?

Comment: Truth be told, I'm not sure of anything. This stems out of https://github.com/roccobarbi/il2missionplanner.link, which I picked up from https://github.com/gavincabbage/il2missionplanner.com as the original project was abandoned and stopped working. And I'm learning leaflet on the go as I try to patch it up to a working condition. So many design decisions are inherited from the previous project. I'm sure something is off with the coordinates because I had to invert the tile order, or it would have shown them inverted along the y axis.

Comment: In fact, the code on the question is an attempt at building a minimal, working map from scratch, so that I can understand what is broken and why, and I can try to design a fix that makes sense.

Comment: Do read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381346/how-to-set-up-leaflet-for-a-non-geographical-tile-grid-with-inverted-y-coordinat , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622737/vertical-alignment-of-tms-tiles-in-leaflet-using-epsg25832-projection/62625435#62625435 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305306/invert-y-axis-of-lcrs-simple-map-on-vue2-leaflet/62320569#62320569 - and if possible try to get the in-game coordinates of a couple of landmarks, as that'll work better to ensure that tile & CRS alignment are OK.

Comment: I read and reread the posts, and many others. They are useful, but I don't think they entirely solve my issue. After a few changes, I now figure out that the issue is really just a zoom issue. At max zoom, I can pinpoint landmarks very accurately. Except that they don't map correctly at any other zoom level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that your raster image is tiled in a *weird* manner.

I strongly believe that the origin of coordinates is lower-left, because of how the 0,0,0 tile is aligned to the bottom-left, leaving white space at the top and at the right:

[image: z0 tiles]

Tiles for zoom level 1 also align to the bottom-left:

[image: z1 tiles]

At zoom level 2, things get *interesting*:

[image: z2 tiles]

Now, *if* the origin of coordinates is at the bottom-left, the origin of tile coordinates ***should*** be at the bottom-left as well.

That is not the case. If it *were*, then this would be a TMS-style tilelayer, with the tile Y coordinate going "up", and Leaflet would need to have a non-infinite CRS with defined bounds, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622737/vertical-alignment-of-tms-tiles-in-leaflet-using-epsg25832-projection/62625435#62625435), and stuff would work, and everyone would be happy.

So, in other words: the 0th (vertical) pixel is at the bottom-left, but the 0th (vertical) tile is at the top-left.

A non-trivial-to-notice consequence of this way of slicing tiles is that the top-left coordinate of the topmost-leftmost tile varies with the zoom level.

So for the zoom level 0 tile, the cartesian Y coordinate of the topmost tiles is 2^15 = 32768, but z1 it's 2^14 = 16384. For z2 and z3 it's 16384 again, but for z4 it's `7*(2^11) = 14336`, for z5 it's `13*(2^10) = 13312`. In the general case, it's the height of your image (12791) padded to the nearest higher power-of-two of the zoom level plus 7 (something like... `Math.pow(2,7+z) * Math.ceil( 12791 / Math.pow(2,7+z) )`, I believe).

The cleanest hack to deal with this (*that I can think of*) is something similar to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381346/how-to-set-up-leaflet-for-a-non-geographical-tile-grid-with-inverted-y-coordinat), like

```
    var map = L.map("map", {

        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: -7,
        maxZoom: 2
    });

    var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://d1w6xpzk1h0aj5.cloudfront.net/kuban/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: -7,
        maxNativeZoom: 0,
        zoomOffset: 7
    }).addTo(map);

    tiles.getTileUrl = function(coords) {
        if (coords.z === -7) {coords.y += 1}
        if (coords.z === -6) {coords.y += 1}
        if (coords.z === -5) {coords.y += 2}
        if (coords.z === -4) {coords.y += 4}
        if (coords.z === -3) {coords.y += 7}
        if (coords.z === -2) {coords.y += 13}
        if (coords.z === -1) {coords.y += 25}
        if (coords.z ===  0) {coords.y += 50}
        
        return L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.bind(tiles)(coords);
    }
```

I've put that in a [working example, over here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yyYBsykXrWI6aQaJ).

---

**I strongly recommend that you slice your image into tiles in a more sensible way**.

If your coordinate system is cartesian, the [gravity](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) of the sliced tiles *should* be bottom-left (i.e. empty space should be at the top and at the right), and the 0-0 tile for any given zoom level *should* contain the bottommost-leftmost pixel.

Likewise, if your coordinate system is screen-like (cartesian with inverted Y, see [this answer for an explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305306/invert-y-axis-of-lcrs-simple-map-on-vue2-leaflet/62320569#62320569)), then the gravity of the sliced tiles *should* be top-left (i.e. empty space should be bottom and right), and the 0-0 tile for any given zoom level *should* contain the topmost-leftmost pixel.

If tiles are not sliced this way, things will get confusing (as is your case).

Comment: Thanks a million. I suppose that's what you get when you inherit tiles sliced years ago by someone else, I would never have spotted this. I will definitely proceed as suggested and slice the tiles anew from the full map.