# Marker position changes with higher zoom level on leaflet map with custom tiles

Tags: leaflet, position, openstreetmap, marker

I transformed an image into maptiles with max zoomlevel of 6. There are several markers on this map. Until zoom level 4 everything is ok. With zoom level > 5 the marker position changes.

I use CRS.simple for the construction of the map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875438/leafletjs-markers-move-on-zoom?noredirect=1&lq=1 . It's hard to judge whether this is a `iconanchor` issue or a tiling issue (e.g. not power-of-two scale on custom tiling) without some code or screenshots.

Comment: it does not use a custom icon, just standard icon

Comment: var map = L.map('map', {
crs: L.CRS.Simple,  minZoom: 0,maxZoom:6
});
L.tileLayer('https://.............../maptiles/output7/{z}/tile_{x}_{y}.png', {
     noWrap: true,
  attribution: 'My Tile Server'

}).addTo(map);
map.setView( [-180,130], 2);  L.marker([-169,127]).addTo(map).bindPopup('test');

Comment: Try a `L.CircleMarker` for good measure. Where do the tiles come from, how were they made?

Comment: ok. Tiles were made with this code: https://github.com/jahed/maptiles/blob/master/README. Source is an image 8400 x 8400.

Comment: Weird, that should be respecting the power-of-two scales. Check that you're not hitting the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69098129/leaflet-non-geographical-map-with-tilelayer-the-map-appears-to-have-a-vertical/69111559#69111559 , though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I recreated the tiles with another codebase: https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet. This worked out well. Markers keep their position. There is also HTML/JS-Code for the leaflet map.